# React-navigation not always pass parameters to screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm migrating my old project (from RN 0.57) to latest one (0.62.2), but I'm having some troubles with react-navigation v5.
I have one screen called "Race" where I have racers and their times. When user click in one specific racer, a new screen (called 'PersonalRank') are open with data from this particular racer.
This second screen takes `tx_id` as parameter to get data from redux/state. The problem is that not always this data is being passed to screen. I have made a little video to show the problem in simulator (the same happens on real smartphone). As you can see in log screen, the `tx_i` is correct while calling the new screen.....but is not always changing in the props of new screen.
This is the URL of demo video: https://youtu.be/pjhH6pOMRhs (1:55 minute video).

In the races list, I'm using this code to call the second screen (note console.log in first line):

```
return (
            <ListItem onPress={() => {  console.log("Navegando para o TXID:", tx_id);   this.props.navigation.navigate("PersonalRank",{tx_id});    } } NoIndent style={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 0, paddingTop: 0, marginBottom: 0, paddingBottom: 5, marginLeft: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginRight: 0}}>
                <Grid>
                    <Col size={10}>
                        <Row><Text style={{paddingLeft: 4}}>#{position}</Text></Row>
                        {temperature > 0 && settings.disp_temp == true &&
                        <Row><Text style={{fontSize: 10, paddingLeft: 4, color: temp_color, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{temperature}ºC</Text></Row>
                        }
                        {speed > 0 && 
                        <Row><Text style={{fontSize: 10, paddingLeft: 4, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{speed.toFixed(2)} Km/h</Text></Row>
                        }
                    </Col>
                    <Col size={90}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col size={67}><Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 14}}>{getPilotName(tx_id)} (ID:{tx_id})</Text></Col>
                            <Col size={33}><Text style={{fontSize: 10, alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: 3}}>{translate('total_time',{...i18n_opt})}: {msToTime(total_time)}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('laps',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('last_lap',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('best_lap',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemHeaderText}>{translate('best_time',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemHeaderText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>{translate('diff',{...i18n_opt})}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>{laps.length}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, {fontWeight: 'bold'}]}>{msToTime(last_time)}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={styles.itemValueText}>{best_lap}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText, { color: '#90db18', fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>{msToTime(best_time)}</Text></Col>
                            <Col><Text style={[styles.itemValueText,styles.itemAlignRight, {marginRight: 5}]}>{diff}</Text></Col>
                        </Row>
                        {settings.show_estimate_pg &&
                        <Row>
                            <Col><ProgressBar style={styles.progress} progress={pg} width={null} /></Col>
                        </Row>
                        }
                    </Col>
                </Grid>
            </ListItem>
        );
```

Now, in the PersonalRank screen, I'm getting tx_id in render() function...but sometime is doesn't work (even waiting for a  while) (see video). The screen opens, but with the last opened tx_id.....sometimes it opens and after a few seconds, it changes.

```
  render() {
    const { pilots, settings } = this.props;
    const { dispatchDelPilot } = this.props;
    const tx_id = this.props.route.params.tx_id;
    const name = getPilotName(tx_id);
    const { dispatchDeleteLap, dispatchSplitLap } = this.props;

    //console.log("ROUTE: ",this.props.route);

    console.log("TX id (from props): ",tx_id);

    const { race } = this.props;
    let laps = [];
    let pilot = "";

    var laps_out = [];
    var last_time = 0;
    var fastest_time = 999999999;
    var fastest_index = 0;
    var last_speed = 0;
    var total_time = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < race.length; i++) {
      if (race[i].tx_id == tx_id) {
        pilot = race[i].pilot;
        laps = race[i].laps;
        total_time = race[i].total_time;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (laps.length <= 0) {
      //this.props.navigation.navigate("CurRace");
      return <Text>No laps for this racer.</Text>;
    }

    let chart_values = [];
    let chart_temperature_values = [];

    let chart_labels = [];
    let has_speed = false;
    let has_bat = false;

    //console.log("Laps: ",laps);

    laps.map((item, index) => {
      if (settings.show_pers_chart) {
        chart_labels.push(index + 1);

        chart_values.push(msToTime(item.time));

        if ("temperature" in item) {
          if (item.temperature > 0) {
          }
        }
      }

      if ("speed" in item) {
        if (item.speed > 0) {
          if (item.speed > last_speed) {
            last_speed = item.speed;
          }
          has_speed = true;
        }
      }

      if ("battery" in item) {
        if (item.battery > 0) {
          has_bat = true;
        }
      }

      if (item.time > last_time) {
        item.diff = "+" + msToTimeDiff(item.time - last_time);
        item.diff_style = { color: "#ea2b12" };
        last_time = item.time;
      } else if (item.time < last_time) {
        item.diff = "-" + msToTimeDiff(last_time - item.time);
        item.diff_style = { color: "#12ea5a" };
        last_time = item.time;
      } else {
        item.diff = "0";
        last_time = item.time;
        item.diff_style = null;
      }

      if (last_time < fastest_time) {
        fastest_index = index;
        fastest_time = last_time;
      }
      // Clear fastest style
      item.fastest_style = null;

      // Key
      item.key = index.toString();

    });

    laps[0].diff = "0";
    let has_temp = chart_temperature_values.length > 0 ? true : false;

    laps[fastest_index].fastest_style = { color: "#12ea5a" };

    const laps2 = laps;



    const renderHiddenItem = (data, rowMap) => (
      <View style={styles.rowBack}>
        <Text>Left</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnLeft]}
          onPress={() => {


            this.setState({
              ...this.state,
              visibleModal: true,
              cur_tx_id: tx_id,
              cur_lap: data.item.lap
            });


          }}
        >

          <MaterialCommunityIcons
                          name="arrow-split-vertical"
                          size={20}
                          color="#5e69d9"
                        />


        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]}
          onPress={() => {


                if (laps.length > 1) {                  
                  console.log("Data: ",data.item);
                  console.log("Apagando tx_id: ",tx_id,", Volta: ",data.item.lap,", Show alerts: ",settings.show_alerts);
                  dispatchDeleteLap(
                    tx_id,
                    data.item.lap,
                    settings.show_alerts
                  );
                } else {
                  alert(
                    translate("cant_del_single_lap", { ...i18n_opt })
                  );
                }


           }}
        >
          <Icon active name="trash" size={20} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );



    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
              <Icon name="arrow-back" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>{name}</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button
              transparent
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("RCharts", { tx_id })
              }
            >
              <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name="chart-bar" />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>

        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.visibleModal === true}
          animationIn={"slideInLeft"}
          animationOut={"slideOutRight"}
        >
          {this._renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 8 }}>
              <ScrollView>
                <ViewShot ref="PersonalRankShot">
                  <View style={styles.line} collapsable={false}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 3 }}>
                      <Text style={[styles.alignCen, styles.headerTitle]}>
                        {translate("lap", { ...i18n_opt })}
                      </Text>
                    </View>

                    {chart_temperature_values.length > 0 && (
                      <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
                        <Text style={[styles.alignCen, styles.headerTitle]}>
                          {translate("temperature", { ...i18n_opt })}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    )}

                    <View style={{ flex: 9 }}>
                      <Text style={[styles.alignCen, styles.headerTitle]}>
                        {translate("time", { ...i18n_opt })}
                      </Text>
                    </View>

                    {has_speed && (
                      <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
                        <Text style={[styles.alignCen, styles.headerTitle]}>
                          {translate("speed", { ...i18n_opt })}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    )}

                    {has_bat && (
                      <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
                        <Text style={[styles.alignCen, styles.headerTitle]}>
                          {translate("bat", { ...i18n_opt })}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    )}

                    <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
                      <Text
                        style={[
                          { paddingRight: 10 },
                          styles.alignRig,
                          styles.headerTitle
                        ]}
                      >
                        {translate("diff", { ...i18n_opt })}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>




                  <View style={styles.container}>
                    <SwipeListView
                      data={laps2}
                      disableRightSwipe={true}
                      renderItem={(data, rowMap) => (
                        <View style={styles.rowFront}>





                          <PersonalRankItem
                            dados={data.item}
                            settings={settings}
                            hasTemp={has_temp}
                            hasSpeed={has_speed}
                            hasBat={has_bat}
                          />






                        </View>
                      )}
                      renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem}
                      leftOpenValue={75}
                      rightOpenValue={-90}
                      previewRowKey={'0'}
                      previewOpenValue={-40}
                      previewOpenDelay={3000}

                    //onRowDidOpen={onRowDidOpen}
                    />
                  </View>


                </ViewShot>

              </ScrollView>


            </View>

          </View>


        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.bt_share}
          onPress={() => this._captureChart()}
        >
          <Icon name="share" size={20} color="#ffffff" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

That am I missing here?
This used to work in old version of RN and react-navigation (4) without any problem.